# PHP: new operator on an object instance creates an object instance. Why?

Tags: php, oop, new-operator

What is the reason the following code works and generates the given result. Is it a special language construct that is just supported by PHP? If so, then which one? Or is it just a simple php-ism?

```
class Foo {};

$a = new Foo();
$b = new $a();

var_dump($a); // class Foo#1 (0)
var_dump($b); // class Foo#2 (0)
```

Comment: It is mentioned in Manual that this is available since PHP 5.3 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Comment: ^ look at: Example #5 Creating new objects (in the above link)

Comment: Question is not about examples and where to see them, question is "why this works".

Comment: Five upvotes in 10 minutes? Wow. It seems this question is much better than I believed...

Comment: @u_mulder I doubt there is a better explanation than that it's just a php-ism, even though I would like to get a reasonable reason for this to exist..

Comment: I think the "why" of some specific language feature is pretty off-topic for SO...

Comment: @MartynasJanuškauskas As you said, it looks like this is just php-ism, more likely because of the fact that PHP is loosely typed, so instead of if conditions with checks like `is_object()` etc,you could directly create a new object from the current one. IMO, it just makes your code less verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP allows you to create an object instance from a variable like this:

```
$a = 'Foo';
$b = new $a;
```

So when you use the `new $a`, PHP is checking if it's a string to make a new instance of the class, and if it's an object, it's going to retrieve the class name of the object instance and make a new instance from it.

If you try to do the same with a non-string or non-object variable:

```
$a = 1;
$b = new $a;
```

This will generate an error:

> PHP Error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string

PHP 5.3.0 introduced a couple of new ways to create instances of an object, which is an example of a scenario like you've provided:

```
class Test {}

$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
```

For more information: Read **Example #5 Creating new objects under** https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Comment: Do you have a link to the RFC that has changed this? Why was it added to PHP? Why is it useful?

Comment: `$b = new get_class($a);` throws me a fatal error. I am sure there is some syntactical mistake. If I store the return in a variable, it runs fine.

Comment: @u_mulder are you sure you read more than a single line of this answer?